# Hibernate: I don't want delete child

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I'm italian and i apologize for my english.

I have two POJO classes that rappresents a parent and a child table in my Db.

Parent. Persona.java

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nome", length = 30, nullable = false)   
private String nome;

@Column(name = "cognome", length = 30, nullable = false)
private String cognome;

@Column(name = "eta")
private int eta;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "persona", orphanRemoval = false)
@Column(nullable = true)
private List<Telefono> numeriDiTelefono;

// Others getters and setters
```

Child. Telefono.java

```
@Id
@Column(name = "numero_telefono")
private String numeroDiTelefono;

@Column(name = "tipo")
private String tipo;


@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
@JoinColumn(name = "persona_id", nullable = true)
private Persona persona;

// Others getters and setters
```

I have used annotations for mapping those classes in database.

When i try to delete a Persona from the database, hibernate delete the associated Telefono with that Persona, I don't want it.
I would that the child references to has a null value in the field persona_id in the Telefono table, how to obtaining that results? What annotations shoulds I used?
Thanks for everyone.

Comment: If you remove CascadeType.REMOVE from the mapping of @ManyToOne, it should not delete the child. Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Yes I try this thing, but in this case nothing is deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA is not magic.

As @Andy Dufresne suggested, remove the `CascadeType.REMOVE` annotation. Then you have to set `Persona` to `null` in the `Telefono`, and clear the `Telefono` collection of the `Persona` before removing the `Persona` from the persistence context. So you have to remove all associations.

You can even combine this with the [`@PreRemove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PreRemove.html) annotation.

Comment: If I set Persona to null, before to remove record from database, and remove a CascaType.Remove the record is updated, but not deleted...

Comment: Which record? This way the Telefono should be updated and the Persona removed. You have to remove the association from both sides.

Comment: I solved. I set to null the child side of the association, and then remove the entity from the dabatase. That's works fine. Thanks to everyone.